# Django one page website with lateral navbar

Tags: ajax, django

My current setup looks like this(from [here](https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar), mostly):

[image]

This is the result of my `home` view. What I intend on doing is keep those 2 sidebars in place and refresh only the `content part`.

My question: What is the obvious solution to this in django?

From what I read so far it seems to be using Ajax to see what exactly the user clicks on the sidebars and return only a part of the HTML which would be the `div` where all the `content` is. (or return a JSON and refresh that `div` depending on the JSON values?)

I need to avoid refreshing the entire page, it seems useless. I could forget about Ajax and just run on separate views but I would have to pass every time a context variable to populate the sidebars depending on the user and this seems to be an overkill.

Even more specific: On the push of a button on the navbar now that is a `href`- links to another page. In order to make it refresh only part of the page what should the button trigger? Should it trigger a jquery function or is there a better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your concern is only about left sidebar calculations, then you can go with caching

Django allows to cache [part of page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching) - sidebar is ideal item for caching. If sidebar is different for users (I see at least `playlists` menu item), then it's also possible to implement fragment caching per user, check [Vary on headers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/cache/#using-vary-headers) part of documentation.

Using ajax will complicate your development process - generate html/json encode/render it on user side, etc, etc. And now almost no one uses django in this way. If you want pure single page application, then I suggest you to take a look at some javascript framework like Angular, Vue or React + Django API backend.

Comment: I did manage to do it via ajax but now i'm slowly starting to adhere to your suggestion. Thank you!